# How to transform two set of discrete points ( vectors ) to help plotting them on a common scale

Tags: algorithm, math, matplotlib

I have two set of discrete points

G1: (x,y1), where y1 in integer range [1..90] ( say )

G2: (x, y2), where y2 in integer range [1..110]

These sets of points are of different length but I would like to compare their plots on a common scale.

That is, I need to display these graphical plots in single figure with a common scale ( say [1..100] ).

I would like to know how I can do the same. How must I transform these vectors to plot it in a common scale ?

P.S. I'd like to specify problem.

So, lets consider two lists:
len(d1) = 110, and he contain some values.
len(d2) = 80.
I'd like to build these graphics in one picture (with using matplotlib). 
len(x) = 110 - just range from 0 to 110

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, d1, 'k-')
ax.plot(x, d2, 'c--')
```

So, if I just multiply elements of list d2 on some coefficient, I'll get only 80 elements, and it can't use this for plot graph. Also I must to fill missed values, but I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: Does the scale matter? Why not just scale one into the other?

Comment: In general case, matter only single scale. I'd like to build graphics in one picture. But I can't build transform function

Comment: If all you want is to scale a number A in range [a1,a2] to range [b1,b2], then B= b1 + (A-a1)*(b2-b1)/(a2-a1)

Comment: Lior, I've just added specific information to my question.

Comment: OK. I know nothing about matplotlib, but maybe you want to compare two time series that were sampled in different rates (e.g. 90 samples per hour and 110 samples per hour) so you'll be able to compare them. Basically, you'll need to interpolate and resample. If it is just for visualization though, there are probably much simpler ways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you need to [upsample / interpolate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsampling) the vector with fewer samples to get more samples and  [downsample / decimate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(signal_processing)) the 
vector with higher samples to get fewer samples ( In essence matching the sampling rate of both the vectors ).

I used [`scipy.signal.resample`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html#scipy-signal-resample) to do the up / down sampling.

I tried to simulate your situation using two random vectors of unequal sample sizes.

See if this helps you out :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal  
# scipy.signal module contains a interpolator / decimator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Creating random vectors for a and b

vector_a = np.sin(2*3.14*100*np.arange(130))  
# Sine signal with 100Hz freq and 130 time samples

vector_b = np.cos(2*3.14*100*np.arange(80))
# Cosine signal with 100Hz freq and 80 time samples

# To avoid bias towards any one vector length take the
# mean of the two sample lengths as the common sample length

common_no_of_samples = (vector_a.shape[0] + vector_b.shape[0]) // 2 
# 105 Samples

# Upsample vector_a to have common_no_of_samples
vector_a = signal.resample(vector_a, common_no_of_samples)
# Downsample vector_b to have common_no_of_samples
vector_b = signal.resample(vector_b, common_no_of_samples)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.arange(common_no_of_samples), vector_a, 'k-')
ax.plot(np.arange(common_no_of_samples), vector_b, 'c--')

# Where np.arange(common_no_of_samples) refers to the common time axis
# vector_a and vector_b are the resampled vectors.
```

[image]

If you want as points in [image] you could do :

```
time_axis = np.arange(common_no_of_samples)
vector_a = np.dstack((vector_a, time_axis))
```

This will generate points of the form :

```
array([[[  2.23656191e-02,   0.00000000e+00],
    [ -3.96584073e-01,   1.00000000e+00],
    [ -7.01262520e-01,   2.00000000e+00],
    [ -9.31867589e-01,   3.00000000e+00],
    [ -9.95165113e-01,   4.00000000e+00],
    [ -9.24625413e-01,   5.00000000e+00],
    [ -6.96587056e-01,   6.00000000e+00],
    [ -3.74795767e-01,   7.00000000e+00],
    [  1.59956385e-02,   8.00000000e+00],
    [  3.94192306e-01,   9.00000000e+00],
    [  7.20969109e-01,   1.00000000e+01],
    [  9.28803144e-01,   1.10000000e+01],
    [  1.00160878e+00,   1.20000000e+01],
    [  9.13659002e-01,   1.30000000e+01],
    [  6.91934367e-01,   1.40000000e+01],
    [  3.57910455e-01,   1.50000000e+01],
```